# Generating Comma Separated Values

Tags: c#, .net, string

Suppose I have a collection of strings:

```
"foo"
"bar"
"xyz"
```

And I would like to generate a comma separated values from the list into something like:

```
"foo, bar, xyz"
```

Notice the lack of ", " at the end.

I am aware that there are dozens of ways to generate this:

- use for-loop and string.Format() or StringBuilder.
- use integer counter and remove the ending ", " if the value > 0
- don't put ", " on the first run
- etc.

Sample code of what I have right now:

```
if (strs.Count() > 0)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var str in strs)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", str);
  return sb.Remove(0, 2).ToString();
}
```

What is the best code that is highly reusable for the above scenario, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String.Join is the right answer, but in the case of an IEnumerable, Linq is often shorter than a for loop:

```
someStringCollection.Aggregate((first, second) => first + ", " + second);
```

Answer (score 26):

You want to use the [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method, which exists in the BCL for this purpose.

Example:

```
var myArray = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var output = string.Join(", ", myArray);
```

Or if you're using .NET 3.5, you can do this with any `IEnumerable<string>` as such:

```
var output = string.Join(", ", myEnumerable.ToArray());
```

(Note that this doesn't give the best performance as it requires, although it is clearly still 'O(n)', and should be suitable for almost all cases).

Now, if your enumerable is not of type `string` (generically an `IEnumerable<T>`), you can just use the `Select` method to convert the result into a string, e.g.

```
var output = string.Join(", ", myEnumerable.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray());
```

---

I'm not sure if you're dealing with values that may potentially contains commas in themselves, but this can be worked around by enclosing them in quotes (`"`) and escaping the quotes, similarly to the CSV format.

```
var output = string.Join(", ", items.Select(x => x.Contains(",") ?
    "\"" + x.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"" : x);
```

Of course, splitting them back up again is a slightly triciker task, which requires a bit of regex.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know this function exists (makes my question look bad).

Comment: @Adrian: No worries. If you're not from a .NET background, discovering new things in the framework isn't is always straightforward - it's an ongoign process of building up familiarity.

Comment: That's the problem, I've been doing .NET since the first version. Duh.

Comment: Heh, well we're all still learning new features of the BCL. I think the fact that your question has been voted up shows it wasn't a stupid question. :)

Comment: You'll want to be careful here.  If any of the strings contains a comma, it will throw the csv off.

Comment: @yodaj007: Indeed, he'll need to use a slightly more complicated method for that, and splitting would need to be done using a regex or such. It's not specified in the question however, so I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Comment: @Noldorin No, that won't be necessary. Version 1 of your answer is good enough.

Comment: @Adrian: I suspected so. It's there anyway however, in case it might help others. :)

Answer (score 4):

As others have said: `String.Join` is *normally* the best way to do this.  But what if you have just have an IEnumerable rather than an array?  Perhaps you have code to enumerate these as you read them from a file using deferred execution.  In this case String.Join isn't quite as nice, because you have to loop over the strings twice — once to create the array and once to join it.  In that case, you want something more like this:

```
public static string ToDelimitedString(this IEnumerable<string> source, string delimiter)
{
    string d = "";
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach( string s in source)
    {
       result.Append(d).Append(s);
       d = delimiter;
    } 
    return result.ToString();
}
```

This will perform *almost* as well as String.Join, and works in the more general case.  Then, given a string array or any other IEnumerable you can call it like this:

```
string finalStr = MyStrings.ToDelimitedString(",");
```

Comment: Yes, that's apparently the more common scenario. IEnumerable<string> than string[].

Comment: +1 The 'result.Append(d).Append(s)' is interesting ... never even thought of that.  It'd be kind of neat to see how many different ways this simple task is currently being done.

Comment: The really cool thing is the jitter will normally optimize the extra assignments away, so the code does _exactly_ what you want it o.

Answer (score 3):

```
string finalstr = String.Join(",", strs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
string s = string.Join (",", new string[] {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Join](http://hushpuppies.opusproofing.com/pdp.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of strings, go with [Noldorin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245210/generating-comma-separated-values/1245225#1245225)'s solution.

But if it's some other collection type, I might do this:

```
if (strs.Count() > 0)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var str in strs)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", (0 == sb.Length ? "" : ","), str);
  return sb.ToString();
}
```